# SQL query to replace a substring

Tags: sql, replace, substring

I wish to write a query which will replace the value0.00 with "-" in a column.
The value should  only be replaced if the value is 0.00 and not if 230.00

I did this query `replace(SUBSTRING(cast(columname AS varchar(7)),0,7),'0.00','-')`
but it replaces 230.00 as 23-

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a table format like so:

```
`id` | `cost`
 1   | 230.00
 2   | 543.65
 3   | 0.00
```

Then a query of

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cost=0 THEN '-' ELSE cost END FROM table;
```

will return

```
230.00
543.65
-
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
if (SUBSTRING(cast(columname AS varchar(7)),0,7) = '0.00', '-', SUBSTRING(cast(columname AS varchar(7)),0,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN columname = 0 THEN '0.00' ELSE replace(SUBSTRING(cast(columname AS varchar(7)),0,7),'0.00','-') END